# ¿Cómo mandar a llamar una variable creada en el archivo custom.js para utilizarla en la base_view.php?

Tags: php, javascript

Quisiera saber como puedo mandar a llamar esta variable $SIDEBAR_MENU = $('#sidebar-menu') que se encuentra declarada en un archivo llamado custom.js para poder utilizarla en otro archivo externo que se llama base_view.php.

Por ahora declare la misma variabe $SIDEBAR_MENU = $('#sidebar-menu') en la base_view.php, pero no me obitene el mismo valor que la que mantiene en el custom.js.

Answer (score 0):

Si no te entendía mal...

PHP se ejecuta en el servidor. JAVASCRIPT se ejecuta en el navegador/cliente. No puedes obtener mágicamente valores que están en memoria de un navegador mirando un texto en el servidor.

Lo que tienes que hacer es enviar desde el navegador por internet el valor que quieres obtener en PHP. El PHP entonces trabaja con el valor y le devuelve al navegador el resultado. Entonces el navegador recibe el resultado y lo muestra.

Utiliza XMLHttpRequest para enviar los datos al servidor por una petición post. 
Despues en PHP con la variable $_POST['parametro'] la obtienes. 
Trabajas con el valor y imprimes el resultado con un echo.
Despues en el navegador accedes a la propiedad reaponse del objeto XMLHttpRequest y ya puedes hacer lo que quieras.